# GCM: Show only new messages

Tags: android

I am using GCM in my Android App to send notifications through the devices. But the App shows all notifications will received. But I just want to show the "new" messages, so the old messages should be markes as "read" or something.

Here are my GCM classes:

```
public class NotificationUtils {

    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationUtils() {
    }

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);

        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        if(Config.appendNotificationMessages){
            // store the notification in shared pref first
            AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().addNotification(message);

            // get the notifications from shared preferences
            String oldNotification = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getNotifications();

            List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(oldNotification.split("\\|"));

            for (int i = messages.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(messages.get(i));
            }
        }else{
            inboxStyle.addLine(message);
        }


        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.load_profilepic)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.load_profilepic)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     * */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) AppController.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    public static final String KEY = "key";
    public static final String TOPIC = "topic";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBE = "subscribe";
    public static final String UNSUBSCRIBE = "unsubscribe";


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String key = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
        switch (key) {
            case SUBSCRIBE:
                // subscribe to a topic
                String topic = intent.getStringExtra(TOPIC);
                subscribeToTopic(topic);
                break;
            case UNSUBSCRIBE:
                break;
            default:
                // if key is specified, register with GCM
                registerGCM();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Registering with GCM and obtaining the gcm registration id
     */
    private void registerGCM() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            Log.e(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // sending the registration id to our server
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);

            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {

        // checking for valid login session
        User user = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser();
        if (user == null) {
            // TODO
            // user not found, redirecting him to login screen
            return;
        }

        String endPoint = EndPoints.USER.replace("_ID_", user.getId());

        Log.e(TAG, "endpoint: " + endPoint);

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
                endPoint, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    // check for error
                    if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                        // broadcasting token sent to server
                        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to send gcm registration id to our sever. " + obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("gcm_registration_id", token);

                Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to a topic
     */
    public static void subscribeToTopic(String topic) {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = instanceID.getToken(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            if (token != null) {
                pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
                Log.e(TAG, "Subscribed to topic: " + topic);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: gcm registration id is null");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Topic subscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(AppController.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), "Topic subscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribeFromTopic(String topic) {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            if (token != null) {
                pubSub.unsubscribe(token, "");
                Log.e(TAG, "Unsubscribed from topic: " + topic);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: gcm registration id is null");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Topic unsubscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Topic subscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public class MyGcmPushReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = MyGcmPushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from   SenderID of the sender.
     * @param bundle Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *               For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        Boolean isBackground = Boolean.valueOf(bundle.getString("is_background"));
        String flag = bundle.getString("flag");
        String data = bundle.getString("data");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.d(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.d(TAG, "flag: " + flag);
        Log.d(TAG, "data: " + data);

        if (flag == null)
            return;

        if(AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser() == null){
            // user is not logged in, skipping push notification
            Log.e(TAG, "user is not logged in, skipping push notification");
            return;
        }

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        switch (Integer.parseInt(flag)) {
            case Config.PUSH_TYPE_CHATROOM:
                // push notification belongs to a chat room
                processChatRoomPush(title, isBackground, data);
                break;
            case Config.PUSH_TYPE_USER:
                // push notification is specific to user
                processUserMessage(title, isBackground, data);
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processing chat room push message
     * this message will be broadcasts to all the activities registered
     * */
    private void processChatRoomPush(String title, boolean isBackground, String data) {
        if (!isBackground) {

            try {
                JSONObject datObj = new JSONObject(data);

                String chatRoomId = datObj.getString("chat_room_id");

                JSONObject mObj = datObj.getJSONObject("message");
                Message message = new Message();
                message.setMessage(mObj.getString("message"));
                message.setId(mObj.getString("message_id"));
                message.setCreatedAt(mObj.getString("created_at"));

                JSONObject uObj = datObj.getJSONObject("user");

                // skip the message if the message belongs to same user as
                // the user would be having the same message when he was sending
                // but it might differs in your scenario
                if (uObj.getString("user_id").equals(AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser().getId())) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Skipping the push message as it belongs to same user");
                    return;
                }

                User user = new User();
                user.setId(uObj.getString("user_id"));
                user.setEmail(uObj.getString("email"));
                user.setName(uObj.getString("name"));
                message.setUser(user);

                // verifying whether the app is in background or foreground
                if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

                    // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                    Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("type", Config.PUSH_TYPE_CHATROOM);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("chat_room_id", chatRoomId);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                    // play notification sound
                    NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils();
                    notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                } else {

                    // app is in background. show the message in notification try
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("chat_room_id", chatRoomId);
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, user.getName() + " : " + message.getMessage(), message.getCreatedAt(), resultIntent);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            // the push notification is silent, may be other operations needed
            // like inserting it in to SQLite
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processing user specific push message
     * It will be displayed with / without image in push notification tray
     * */
    private void processUserMessage(String title, boolean isBackground, String data) {
        if (!isBackground) {

            try {
                JSONObject datObj = new JSONObject(data);

                String imageUrl = datObj.getString("image");

                JSONObject mObj = datObj.getJSONObject("message");
                Message message = new Message();
                message.setMessage(mObj.getString("message"));
                message.setId(mObj.getString("message_id"));
                message.setCreatedAt(mObj.getString("created_at"));

                JSONObject uObj = datObj.getJSONObject("user");
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(uObj.getString("user_id"));
                user.setEmail(uObj.getString("email"));
                user.setName(uObj.getString("name"));
                message.setUser(user);

                // verifying whether the app is in background or foreground
                if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

                    // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                    Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("type", Config.PUSH_TYPE_USER);
                    pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                    // play notification sound
                    NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils();
                    notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                } else {

                    // app is in background. show the message in notification try
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                    // check for push notification image attachment
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                        showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, user.getName() + " : " + message.getMessage(), message.getCreatedAt(), resultIntent);
                    } else {
                        // push notification contains image
                        // show it with the image
                        showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message.getMessage(), message.getCreatedAt(), resultIntent, imageUrl);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            // the push notification is silent, may be other operations needed
            // like inserting it in to SQLite
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     * */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     * */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
}

public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = MyInstanceIDListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
     * InstanceID provider.
     */
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onTokenRefresh");
        // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GcmIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

So, how can I just show the new notifications and not all which received from all time.